# Recovering an Image from an array in php (drupal enviroment)

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

I am trying to use php to get an image from an array in Drupal. At the moment when printing this array other variables are printed as well. What i need is a way to search this array for an image such as this ->

```
<img src="blah.jpg" alt="blah" />
```

and then save this as a separate variable. I'm unsure how to approach this sort of problem.

Perhaps a regex function or another in built php function?

I would class my knowledge as pretty low in php so please make your answer as simple as possible

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Have you looked into using Regular Expressions? What did you find out and what is giving you trouble?

Comment: Im unsure how to write regular expressions. I understand you need to use preg replace(?) but as to writing the regular expressions itself i am unsure.

Comment: Well there is tons of documentation about it, like [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [some random guide](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I found this (first result when you Google *php regex img tag*). This show you the required Regular Expression.

```
$content = 'This is a test. <img src="images/foo.jpg" title="foo">';
$res = preg_match_all('/<img[^>]*>/Ui', $content, $matches);
$string =  $matches[0][0];
```

I don't really get your whole array question, but this should probably be enough to achieve your goal!

Good luck!